# Poor performance when using Batch Normalization with batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I noticed a strange effect, When training a Keras model, let's say this one

```py
model9 = Sequential([
    Dense(512, activation='tanh', input_shape = X_train[0].shape),
    Dense(512//2, activation='tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    Dense(512//4, activation='tanh'),
    Dense(512//8, activation='tanh'),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])
model9.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc', 'mse'])
hist9 = model9.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=350,  validation_data=(X_test,y_test), verbose=2)
```

It will perform okay on the validation set. i.e

```
loss9, acc9, mse9 = model9.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print(f"Loss is {loss9},\nAccuracy is {acc9 * 100},\nMSE is {mse9}")
```

And accuracy is 92%.

#### But as soon as I add **batch_size=128** or some other batch_size, my model performance becomes very poor.

i.e accracy drops to 70% or 60%. What is the reason? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default setting is `batch_size=32`. So even if you don't set that parameter, you still have batches.

After every batch, your weights get updated. If you increase your batch_size 4-fold (128), but keep the same number of epochs, you are effectively quartering the number of updates. This can explain the worse performance.

Try increasing the batch-size only a little bit (or even lowering it) and see what happens. Alternatively, increase the number of epochs.